# Don't understand this example with margin collapse

Tags: html, css

I can understand this first example below when we have a border on the outer div.
The margin collapse so we get only 20px margin.

But the second example seems strange how can the margin collapse to zero when we just
remove the border from the outer div

```
/*Fist example */
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>"float: left" with no width set</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body
    {
            padding: 0;
        margin:1px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: yellow; border: solid 1px #ccc;">
            <div style="margin: 20px; background-color: red;">
                <p style="margin: 20px; color:#fff; background-color: blue;">A paragraph 
                     with a  20px margin inside a div, also with a 20px margin</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

/* Secod example without a border on the outer div */
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>"float: left" with no width set</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
     body
     {
         padding: 0;
         margin:1px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:yellow;">
            <div style="margin: 20px; background-color: red;">
                <p style="margin: 20px; color:#fff; background-color: blue;">
                       A paragraph with a 20px margin inside a div, also with a 20px margin
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

//Tony
```

Comment: Is that syntax error supposed to be in the second example?  The float is set outside of the tag

Answer (score 1):

Two margins are adjoining if and only if ... no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them

see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

Because if a border (or padding) separates a block-level parent with it's first in-flow block-level child margins will not collapse. Also note that margins will *not* collapse on an element that is floated, elements that have a display value of `inline-block` or absolutely positioned elements. As Toxz pointed out, take a look at the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) for an in-depth explanation:

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
>   in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has **no** top
>   border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance

Comment: so when we are discussing "collapsing" in this context, does it only refer to what happens to the background?  because it appears that the margin is still "there", producing space, even though it's not yellow: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0EOj3aoWFLS1xFyMhsL?p=preview

Comment: In this context - yes. But if you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8adrR/) and delete the `float: left;` rule on the `<p>` you'll see how it can also affect the positioning of elements. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the example Adrift!  So is there no general definition (or concept) that relates these two examples?  That is, in what cases does the "collapse" affect only background, and in what cases does it affect actual space?  I notice, eg, that I can replace float:left with display:inline-block and the margin space still exists.  Is there a deeper concept at play?

Comment: Unfortunately not - it's dependent upon many variables. An element that is inline-block will never have margin collapsing, just like floats and absolutely/fixed positioned elements - not even with their in-flow, block-level descendants. It's a bit difficult for me to explain, I suggest reading the link both Toxz and I provided to the spec and playing around a bit.